# Android Java AWS SDK S3 Image Upload Callback Functions

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-image

I'm looking for a Android AWS S3 image upload callback function or someway of detecting whether the image uploaded successfully. The documentation didn't seem to list any. I'm following this [Android tutorial](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271).

Could someone advise me on this matter? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, the sample code snippets for Android use a synchronous service client. When a method returns a response object, it means the service call successfully completed. It throws an exception if the request fails.

Comment: Do you know of an async version of the PutObject method?

Comment: [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) is an asynchronous high level client for Amazon S3.